# How to do a correct insensitive sorting of a string list in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

It seems that I cannot sort insensitively a string list correctly. I will give a simple example. I have tried the following methods with lst = ['b', 'B', 'a', 'A'].

1. `lst.sort(key=str.lower)`
2. `lst.sort(key=str.upper)`
3. `lst.sort(key=str.casefold)`

They all give the same result: ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B']. Apparently, this seems correct, but it isn't. The correct result should be ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b'] since 'A' is lower than 'a' and 'B' is lower than 'b' (ASCII-wise).

Is there any other method for a correct insensitive sorting? I mean, like the above, i.e. a one-liner sorting.

Comment: In what sense is that wrong? If you want to sort case-insensitively, then by definition you shouldn't care which way around the case-folded equivalents appear in the output (and Python guarantees _stable_ sorting).

Comment: The functions you apply to make the key case insensitive make 'a' == 'A' so there is no "correct" order.  How they show up in the output is probably input order dependent.

Comment: In what stats do you see those upvotes before downvotes?

Comment: @Apostolos, a Unicode compliant sort would usually yield ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B'] rather than ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b'] since uppercase characters have a tertiary distinction from their lowercase counterpart. Additionally, provided answers aren't universal solutions, they are only valid solutions where secondary collation distinctions aren't required.

Comment: I undertsand what you say @Andj, and from that aspect you are right. But in a strict sense, and in international ASCII and character set tables, **capital letters precede small letters**. And it is clear that it is from that aspect I'm talking about. Not from a Unicode compliant aspect.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy, clicking on the icon with the black cup and a star on it, on top right, shows you the **recent** reputation points you earned or lost on a question or answer you posted. In the present case, I saw +4 and +2 points for my question (among other), which correspond to 3 upvotes, considering that 1 upvote = 2  points.

Comment: No, an upvote gives you 10 points, not 2. Your activity data [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya3W5.png) that the +4 came from down+down+up+down (in that order) and the +2 came from accepting an answer.

Comment: @Apostolos that is true for Basic Latin and Latin-1 Supplement but isn't a universal feature of the Latin script in Unicode. Uppercase letters don't always precede lower letters. Unicode collation always sorts lowercase Latin first by default. But then Python collation isn't based on Unicode.

But restricting ourselves to English, you require up to four levels of sorting, not just two (upper and lowercase), take a list like `['resume', 're-sort', 'Rose', 'result', 'rosé', 'résumé', 'resort', 'rose']` which does require quaternary strength.

Comment: @Andj *"Python collation isn't based on Unicode"* - It's not? Doesn't Python sort strings exactly by Unicode code points?

Comment: @KellyBundy, yes, Python sorts strings by Unicode codepoint, but that isn't what the Unicode Collation Algorithm, nor the CLDR Collation Algorithm do. Python strings are Unicode strings but many Python methods diverge from or do not use the Unicode equivalent. Python does not use Unicode collation.

Comment: @KellyBundy, even when you are doing locale based sorting, Python uses libc implementations rather than Unicode implementations, and results will differ between libc implementations, so vary between operating systems.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy, an upvote for an **answer** gives you 10 points.  An upvote for a **question** gives you 2 points. You can check the rules, policies or help (I don't remember where these things are descibed.) But you can also check your own stats in your profile.

Comment: OK, @Andj.   (I have to type at least 15 characters per policy! )

Comment: I have no idea why you still claim it's 2 points even after I've clearly shown you that it's 10 points.

Comment: I don't **still** claim it, @Kelly  I just talked about it once.  But you are right. I miscalculated the points. I just checked in Help and it says 10 points for questions too. I really didn't remember this. Thanks for mention it! 

Comment: You said it *twice*, in two separate comments, one before and one after mine where I corrected you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to sort the list by alphabet, but you also want additional sorting when dealing with the same character. You can do it by sending a `tuple` to the key

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: (x.lower(), x))
```

Answer (score 2):

The stability works against you in that case. Take advantage of it instead.

```
lst.sort(); lst.sort(key=str.casefold)
```

(I'd put it on two lines but you asked for a one-liner...)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3_XKKSxRsFaLVk9R1FNSdQEQiiHBUj-XiAsrpFecXlWhoWivA2dmplbbFJUV6yYnFqWn5OSmaXFwFRZl5JRpAFZoQU6GGwywBAA)

Comment: @Apostolos Well, of course mine can be a "true" one-liner as well (one statement), e.g., `lst.sort(), lst.sort(key=str.lower)`, which is a few characters shorter than Guy's and quite possibly faster than theirs (I've seen that many times, two such simple sorts being faster than one more complicated sort). But really I'd put it in two lines unless I'm golfing.

Comment: Ha, I thought that you could say that. But a "one-liner" certainly doesn't refer to instructions typed **on a single line**. There can be hundred of them!  Nor does it refer to the total length of all instructions. This is of secondary importance. Anyway, as you correctly pointed out, the solution has also --in fact, mainly-- to do with (code) **efficiency**.

Comment: @Apostolos How efficient are they on your actual data? (How much time and memory do they take?)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading [Python official documentation: Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

Python's `list.sort` and `sorted` are guaranteed to be ***stable*** sorts, which means that if two items are equivalent for the sorting key, then they will appear in the order in which they were in the original list.

Your key is `str.lower`, thus `'a'` and `'A'` are equivalent. Hence they appear in the same order after sorting as they were before sorting. In your original list, `'a'` was before `'A'`, therefore in the final list, `'a'` is before `'A'`.

If you want to include tie-breaking criteria in your key, then you can use a tuple, since tuple are compared lexicographically (which means from left to right) in python:

```py
l = ['b', 'B', 'a', 'A']
l.sort(key=lambda x: (x.lower(), x))   # (alphabetical, then ascii)
print(l)
# ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b']
```

Or you can sort twice, first according to the tie-breaker, then according to the main criterion:

```py
l = ['b', 'B', 'a', 'A']
l.sort()               # tie-break: ascii
l.sort(key=str.lower)  # main criterion: alphabetical
print(l)
# ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b']
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try sorting using ASCII Values available in each programming value for example the value of a is 65 and A is 97 I have tried this method many times it works for me

but if you want to try another approach then you can try this lamda function i resolved your question by this.
list = ['b', 'B', 'a', 'A']
sorted_lst = sorted(list, key=lambda x: (x.lower(), x))